# Can two non-isomorphic connected compact simple Lie groups have homeomorphic underlying manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

I often see connected compact simple Lie groups represented as surfaces.

My question is, are the underlying topological spaces of all compact connected **simple** Lie groups non-homeomorphic?

If this is true, could you outline the reason?

Note compactness is needed because of the counterexample (R,+) and (R^+,*).
And non-simple counterexamples also exist such as U(2) and SU(2)xU(1).

Comment: You might want to add connectedness to your hypothesis, as $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\oplus(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ are diffeomorphic (both are $0$-dimensional manifolds of the same cardinality), but not isomorphic as groups.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67030/if-compact-connected-lie-groups-are-homeomorphic-as-topological-space-are-they

Comment: Thanks for these counterexamples. I was specifically thinking about the connected compact simple Lie groups so I’ve edited the question. I believe there are some fundamental theorems of Lie which may demonstrate the relationship.